# FormData is empty when using jQuery ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I try to submit form with file with `jQuery.ajax`. Google says I should use `FormData` which will automagically encode the file and all inputs into the one object which I can send via XHR.

Well, the `FormData` object is empty. It's empty in the debugger and on the server side. I can't find the error. Here is the code. The browser is Firefox 27.

```html
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="generate_params">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="AJAX_BANNERS_GENERATE">
</form>

<div>
    <p>
        <label>
            Image: <input type="file" name="bg_image[]" form="generate_params" required>
        </label>
    </p>
</div>

<input type="submit" form="generate_params">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#generate_params").submit(function (e) {
            var data = new FormData(this);

            $.ajax({
                data: data,
                method: "POST",
                success: function (url) {
                    alert("ok");
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });

            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

In Firebug on the `Network` tab in the `Params` section I see the line:

[image]

`[object FormData]: "undefined"`? Seriously?

The silly thing that I can't even send `FormData` object created from scratch. Like this

```js
var data = new FormData();
data.append("test", {value: 0}); // still empty
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turned out, I'm using jQuery 1.8.1 which doesn't support `FormData`. Library update solved the problem.

Comment: i am facing problem in jquery2.2.4.min.js

Answer (score 4):

Had exactly the same issue with a Django-backend.
Solved it by adding **name** attributes to all my inputs inside the form, as they are to used to address the form data in a dict/hashmap structure.

Have a good one.

Answer (score 3):

Here is How I would do it:

1. Openning and Closing `Form` tag should wrap all the input files!
2. `e.preventDefault();` should be at the beginning of the function, better practice.

**JS:**

```
$("#generate_params").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if( window.FormData !== undefined ) 
         //make sure that we can use FormData ie>9, chrome > 7, opera > 12 safari >5, android > 3  gecko mobile > 2, opera mobile >12 <- wil support XHR too
    {

        var formData = new FormData(this);
        // you can append aditional values:
        //  formData.append("be",logmebehave);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'filesend.php',  //Path to the server script that process the data
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            xhr: function() {  },
            success: function(response){},
            //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
         });
    } else {

       //Fallback

    }

    return false;
});
```

FormData wil support multi file upload.

Add to your Form tag the attribute:

`enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Should work great!

**NOTE**: You may find that the FILES array is empty on server side page - In this case you need to make sure your server configuration allows file uploads, size limit of file upload is enough, post time
is enough etc....

The best way to begin is to make sure that file uploads is allowed and then testing with very
small files to be sure everything in your code is OK.

Comment: instead of `var formData = new FormData($('#generate_params')[0]);` you can write `var formData = new FormData(this);` instead. 'this' is the actual form when inside the submit handler.

Comment: logging the new FormData gives me an empty object, even though $('#generate_params')[0] shows me the form object. Any ideas?